# can log shipping to log shipping?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have one production SQL Server 2008 Database with log shipping set up for that server in US.

I have a account in the log shipping database so I could sometimes run query on log shipping database.

Now I need to ship data back to Korea daily but I don't want to impact production performance. Can you suggest any technique to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

You can ship the logs to as many sources as you want. Just add a new secondary server on the primary one. The impact will be on the Korean server as it will have to copy the logs from the backup directory and replay them.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to consider if you don't want to impact the connection between the log shipping servers during production hours is to use [Distributed File System (DFS)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753479(v=ws.10).aspx).

You will still need a log shipping secondary in Korea, but you will disable the copy jobs for all the databases on the log shipping secondary.  All you have is the backup job running on the log shipping primary and the restore job on log shipping secondary in Korea.

DFS provides you a lot of flexibility to throttle bandwidth during production hours and then increase during off-hours.  Essentially, DFS would copy all your .trn files directly from the log shipping primary to the log shipping secondary in Korea.